# TinyMCE spellchecker plugin - British English in Google Spell mode

Tags: tinymce, spell-checking

I need to be able to use tinyMCE spellchecker plugin with British English. i.e. a word colour should not be treated as a mistake.
The plugin is set up to use Google Spell.

```
+English=en_GB
```

did not work, and en is only the US writing.

Thank you in advance